# [__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d21350

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

What could this error mean?

```
[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d21350
```

Here is my code:

```
    NSString *urlString = @"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [params setObject:status forKey:@"status"];
    [params setObject:replyToID forKey:@"in_reply_to_status_id"];
    [params setObject:@"1" forKey:@"include_entities"];

    // Build the request with our parameter
    TWRequest *request = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:url parameters:params requestMethod:TWRequestMethodPOST];

    // Attach the account object to this request
    [request setAccount:twitterAccount];

    [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
        if (!responseData) {
            // inspect the contents of error 
            NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);

            self.alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"HTTP error" message:@"I could not connect to the Twitter API." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
            [self.alert show];

            [self.replyDelegate replyRequestSuccessful:NO];
        }
        else {
            /*NSString *responseDataAsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
             NSLog(responseDataAsString);*/

            NSError *error;
            NSArray *replyResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];

            if (!replyResponse) {
                NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);

                self.alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"JSON error" message:@"I could not parse the JSON response from the Twitter API." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
                [self.alert show];

                [self.replyDelegate replyRequestSuccessful:NO];
            }
            else {
                [self.replyDelegate replyRequestSuccessful:YES];
            }
        }
    }];
```

I tried debuggin, and it dies once it enters the performRequestWithHandler. It goes the else block and dies with the error above.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

It means that you are passing an `NSNumber` where the called code expects an `NSString` or some other object that has a `length` method. You can tell Xcode to break on exceptions so that you see where exactly the `length` method gets called.

Comment: More likely, there is an issue with his memory management, and the runtime/framework is expecting an NSString that's not there anymore (from premature deallocation), and an NSNumber has been allocated there instead. If you purposefully try to send `length` to an `NSNumber`, the compiler would hopefully warn you.

Comment: Not if the `NSNumber` is passed in a dictionary or through some other interface that erases the types. But you’re right, it’s quite probable that he’s over-releasing something. It might be a good idea to try with `NSZombieEnabled`.

Comment: What do you mean by "erases the types"?

Comment: If an interface takes an `id` instead of an `NSString`, it’s easily possible to put an `NSNumber` where `NSString` is expected without the compiler noticing. In general, “type erasure” is stripping the explicit type off things. It’s a common problem with collections in some languages: when you put something into an Objective-C collection (like an `NSArray`) and then read it back, the compiler no longer knows the type of the thing, it’s been erased.

Answer (score 6):

Specifically this line of code:

```
[params setObject:replyToID forKey:@"in_reply_to_status_id"];
```

the `replyToID` is not a String or has a method `length`. If you don't have this, or if you convert the `replyToID` to a String before setting it in params it should work.