# Trying to show to multiple label from response which came from web service ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, web-services, uitableview

I am trying to show driver details from web service response in tableview (custom tableview cell for complex design) but the app crashes , I have tried many other alternatives but not working please help here is the code:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    id jsonResponseData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    NSArray * jsonResponseDataArray = [jsonResponseData objectForKey:@"data"];
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [self createMarkerObjectsWithJson:jsonResponseDataArray];
    }];

    [[self driverListTableView] reloadData];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [arrayMain count];
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    //NSLog(@"arrayMain : %@",arrayMain);
    //method to return custom cell
    DriverListTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DriverListTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    //NSLog(@"nsarray: %lu",(unsigned long)[arrayMain count]);
    NSDictionary *testDict = [arrayMain objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"mainDict : %@",testDict);
    NSString *firstName = [testDict objectForKey:@"f_name"];
    NSString *lastName = [testDict objectForKey:@"l_name"];
    NSString  *companyName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",firstName,lastName];
    NSString *basePrice = [testDict objectForKey:@"base_price"];
    NSString *carType = [testDict objectForKey:@"car_type_label"];
    NSString *waitingTime = [testDict objectForKey:@"waiting_time"];
    NSLog(@"d_id %@",companyName);
    cell.labelCompanyName.text = companyName;
    //cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"driver-1.png"];
    cell.labelBasePrice.text = basePrice;
    cell.labelCarType.text = carType;
    cell.labelWaitingTime.text = waitingTime;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSLog(@"selected at index: %ld",(long)indexPath.row);
}

@end
```

here the app creashes when i try to show multiple label in cellForRowAtindexpath method . if you cant understand the question then let me know in the comments i will provide more info.

the jsonResponseData is :

```
{
    count = 131;
    data =     (
                {
            "base_fare" = 20;
            "c_no" = "";
            "c_type" = 1;
            "car_type_label" = "";
            color = "";
            "d_id" = bZ;
            "d_type" = 1;
            "driver_type_label" = "";
            "f_name" = Saikat;
            "l_name" = Singh;
            status = 1;
            "waiting_time" = 8;
        },
                {
            "base_fare" = 20;
            "c_no" = "";
            "c_type" = 2;
            "car_type_label" = "";
            color = "";
            "d_id" = KlCxEa;
            "d_type" = 1;
            "driver_type_label" = "";
            "f_name" = Saikat;
            "l_name" = Singh;
            status = 1;
            "waiting_time" = 20;
        },
                {
            "base_fare" = 20;
            "c_no" = "";
            "c_type" = 3;
            "car_type_label" = "";
            color = "";
            "d_id" = bZHXHX;
            "d_type" = 1;
            "driver_type_label" = "";
            "f_name" = Sourav;
            "l_name" = Prasad;
            status = 1;
            "waiting_time" = 22;
        },
                {
            "base_fare" = 20;
            "c_no" = "";
            "c_type" = 3;
            "car_type_label" = "";
            color = "";
            "d_id" = KlbZCx;
            "d_type" = 1;
            "driver_type_label" = "";
            "f_name" = Sourav;
            "l_name" = Prasad;
            status = 1;
            "waiting_time" = 21;
        },
                {
            "base_fare" = 20;
            "c_no" = "";
            "c_type" = 3;
            "car_type_label" = "";
            color = "";
            "d_id" = KlbZKl;
            "d_type" = 1;
            "driver_type_label" = "";
            "f_name" = Sourav;
            "l_name" = Khan;
            status = 1;
            "waiting_time" = 15;
        },
                {
            "base_fare" = 20;
            "c_no" = "";
            "c_type" = 3;
            "car_type_label" = "";
            color = "";
            "d_id" = KlbZpS;
            "d_type" = 1;
            "driver_type_label" = "";
            "f_name" = Amar;
            "l_name" = Prasad;
            status = 1;
            "waiting_time" = 22;
        },
                {
            "base_fare" = 20;
            "c_no" = "";
            "c_type" = 3;
            "car_type_label" = "";
            color = "";
            "d_id" = KlpSQv;
            "d_type" = 1;
            "driver_type_label" = "";
            "f_name" = Saikat;
            "l_name" = Khan;
            status = 1;
            "waiting_time" = 15;
        },
                {
            "base_fare" = 20;
            "c_no" = "";
            "c_type" = 3;
            "car_type_label" = "";
            color = "";
            "d_id" = KlpSHX;
            "d_type" = 1;
            "driver_type_label" = "";
            "f_name" = Sudipta;
            "l_name" = Singh;
            status = 1;
            "waiting_time" = 7;
        },
                {
            "base_fare" = 20;
            "c_no" = "";
            "c_type" = 3;
            "car_type_label" = "";
            color = "";
            "d_id" = KlEabZ;
            "d_type" = 1;
            "driver_type_label" = "";
            "f_name" = Saikat;
            "l_name" = Khan;
            status = 1;
            "waiting_time" = 6;
        },
                {
            "base_fare" = 20;
            "c_no" = "";
            "c_type" = 3;
            "car_type_label" = "";
            color = "";
            "d_id" = KlQvEa;
            "d_type" = 1;
            "driver_type_label" = "";
            "f_name" = Vasu;
            "l_name" = Prasad;
            status = 1;
            "waiting_time" = 14;
        },
                {
            "base_fare" = 20;
            "c_no" = "";
            "c_type" = 3;
            "car_type_label" = "";
            color = "";
            "d_id" = KlHXmN;
            "d_type" = 1;
            "driver_type_label" = "";
            "f_name" = Saikat;
            "l_name" = Brando;
            status = 1;
            "waiting_time" = 8;
        },
                {
            "base_fare" = 20;
            "c_no" = "";
            "c_type" = 3;
            "car_type_label" = "";
            color = "";
            "d_id" = mNbZCx;
            "d_type" = 1;
            "driver_type_label" = "";
            "f_name" = Saikat;
            "l_name" = Brando;
            status = 1;
            "waiting_time" = 6;
        },
                {
            "base_fare" = 20;
            "c_no" = "";
            "c_type" = 3;
            "car_type_label" = "";
            color = "";
            "d_id" = mNbZEa;
            "d_type" = 1;
            "driver_type_label" = "";
            "f_name" = Vasu;
            "l_name" = Singh;
            status = 1;
            "waiting_time" = 16;
        },
                {
            "base_fare" = 20;
            "c_no" = "";
            "c_type" = 3;
            "car_type_label" = "";
            color = "";
            "d_id" = mNmNEa;
            "d_type" = 1;
            "driver_type_label" = "";
            "f_name" = Vasu;
            "l_name" = Prasad;
            status = 1;
            "waiting_time" = 23;
        },
                {
            "base_fare" = 20;
            "c_no" = "";
            "c_type" = 3;
            "car_type_label" = "";
            color = "";
            "d_id" = mNmNbG;
            "d_type" = 1;
            "driver_type_label" = "";
            "f_name" = Sudipta;
            "l_name" = Singh;
            status = 1;
            "waiting_time" = 20;
        },
                {
            "base_fare" = 20;
            "c_no" = "";
            "c_type" = 3;
            "car_type_label" = "";
            color = "";
            "d_id" = mNOrKl;
            "d_type" = 1;
            "driver_type_label" = "";
            "f_name" = Amar;
            "l_name" = Brando;
            status = 1;
            "waiting_time" = 9;
        },
                {
            "base_fare" = 20;
            "c_no" = "";
            "c_type" = 3;
            "car_type_label" = "";
            color = "";
            "d_id" = mNOrbG;
            "d_type" = 1;
            "driver_type_label" = "";
            "f_name" = Vasu;
            "l_name" = Khan;
            status = 1;
            "waiting_time" = 22;
        },
                {
            "base_fare" = 20;
            "c_no" = "";
            "c_type" = 3;
            "car_type_label" = "";
            color = "";
            "d_id" = mNEamN;
            "d_type" = 1;
            "driver_type_label" = "";
            "f_name" = Sudipta;
            "l_name" = Roy;
            status = 1;
            "waiting_time" = 28;
        },
                {
            "base_fare" = 20;
            "c_no" = "";
            "c_type" = 3;
            "car_type_label" = "";
            color = "";
            "d_id" = mNEapS;
            "d_type" = 1;
            "driver_type_label" = "";
            "f_name" = Vasu;
            "l_name" = Singh;
            status = 1;
            "waiting_time" = 24;
        },
                {
            "base_fare" = 20;
            "c_no" = "";
            "c_type" = 3;
            "car_type_label" = "";
            color = "";
            "d_id" = OrCxKl;
            "d_type" = 1;
            "driver_type_label" = "";
            "f_name" = Vasu;
            "l_name" = Khan;
            status = 1;
            "waiting_time" = 30;
        },
                {
            "base_fare" = 20;
            "c_no" = "";
            "c_type" = 3;
            "car_type_label" = "";
            color = "";
            "d_id" = OrCxmN;
            "d_type" = 1;
            "driver_type_label" = "";
            "f_name" = Vasu;
            "l_name" = Roy;
            status = 1;
            "waiting_time" = 7;
        },
                {
            "base_fare" = 20;
            "c_no" = "";
            "c_type" = 3;
            "car_type_label" = "";
            color = "";
            "d_id" = OrmNbZ;
            "d_type" = 1;
            "driver_type_label" = "";
            "f_name" = Amar;
            "l_name" = Roy;
            status = 1;
            "waiting_time" = 24;
        },
                {
            "base_fare" = 20;
            "c_no" = "";
            "c_type" = 3;
            "car_type_label" = "";
            color = "";
            "d_id" = OrmNQv;
            "d_type" = 1;
            "driver_type_label" = "";
            "f_name" = Vasu;
            "l_name" = Khan;
            status = 1;
            "waiting_time" = 19;
        },
                {
            "base_fare" = 20;
            "c_no" = "";
            "c_type" = 3;
            "car_type_label" = "";
            color = "";
            "d_id" = OrOrCx;
            "d_type" = 1;
            "driver_type_label" = "";
            "f_name" = Amar;
            "l_name" = Khan;
            status = 1;
            "waiting_time" = 19;
        },
                {
            "base_fare" = 20;
            "c_no" = "";
            "c_type" = 3;
            "car_type_label" = "";
            color = "";
            "d_id" = OrOrmN;
            "d_type" = 1;
            "driver_type_label" = "";
            "f_name" = Saikat;
            "l_name" = Khan;
            status = 1;
            "waiting_time" = 22;
        },
                {
            "base_fare" = 20;
            "c_no" = "";
            "c_type" = 3;
            "car_type_label" = "";
            color = "";
            "d_id" = OrEabZ;
            "d_type" = 1;
            "driver_type_label" = "";
            "f_name" = Sourav;
            "l_name" = Khan;
            status = 1;
            "waiting_time" = 12;
        },
                {
            "base_fare" = 20;
            "c_no" = "";
            "c_type" = 3;
            "car_type_label" = "";
            color = "";
            "d_id" = OrHXbZ;
            "d_type" = 1;
            "driver_type_label" = "";
            "f_name" = Amar;
            "l_name" = Brando;
            status = 1;
            "waiting_time" = 25;
        },
                {
            "base_fare" = 20;
            "c_no" = "";
            "c_type" = 3;
            "car_type_label" = "";
            color = "";
            "d_id" = OrHXHX;
            "d_type" = 1;
            "driver_type_label" = "";
            "f_name" = Amar;
            "l_name" = Prasad;
            status = 1;
            "waiting_time" = 29;
        }
    );
}
```

the error

> -[**NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000083 2015-09-19 16:09:42.153 sRider[4995:102757] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000083'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001113a4c65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x000000011103dbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x00000001113ac0ad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] +
>   205   3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011130213c
>   ___forwarding_** + 988    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111301cd8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120  5   UIKit
>   0x0000000111970a74 -[UILabel
>   _textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:includingShadow:] + 65  6   UIKit                               0x00000001119708cf -[UILabel
>   textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:] + 76   7   UIKit
>   0x0000000111974379 -[UILabel _intrinsicSizeWithinSize:] + 170     8
>   UIKit                               0x0000000111974459 -[UILabel
>   intrinsicContentSize] + 76    9   UIKit
>   0x0000000111e12a0c -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout)
>   _generateContentSizeConstraints] + 33     10  UIKit                               0x0000000111e127d0 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout)
>   _updateContentSizeConstraints] + 422  11  UIKit                               0x0000000111e19bc5 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
>   updateConstraints] + 162  12  UIKit
>   0x00000001119742c4 -[UILabel updateConstraints] + 274

Comment: That's a lot of code and no details on the crash type, message or stack trace. Show just the appropriate code and all of the crash details

Comment: agree with @Wain. I'd test the objects populating the array you are calling to load the tableView in a simple view with labels to make sure your not calling an object that doesn't exist. Then I'd check the cell registration to make sure you're doing it right. Also test the array to make sure that you're not trying to populate tableView past the array.count.

Comment: i Have edited the codes to make it short and @noobsmcgoobs I can't really get your point I am new to objective c so please don't make me pull my hairs off.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error seems like I had to change the value I was fetching from array to string as it was coming in NSNumber , so I changed it to NSString by setting the label text to NSString - string with format like this:

```
cell.labelBasePrice.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[testDict objectForKey:@"base_fare"]];
    cell.labelCarType.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[testDict objectForKey:@"car_type_label"]];
    cell.labelWaitingTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Waiting %@",[testDict objectForKey:@"waiting_time"]];
```

Comment: Thanks to @Wain for indicating towards the error in console which I forgot to check , it difficult to get used to this kind of stuff as I am noob. :P

Answer (score 0):

**0x00000001113ac0ad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:]**

This line tells me that you are sending a message to an object that doesn't have some method in it's header.

**-[NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000083 2015-09-19 16:09:42.153 sRider[4995:102757] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]:**

This one specifically tells me that you are sending a `length` method to some NSNumber object that doesn't take that method.

[[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d21350](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095459/nscfnumber-length-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-0x6d21350)

You have to go through your code and see if you are mistaking an NSNumber for an NSString. Take a look at your JSON and try to figure out if you are sending any properties that represent the JSON in your custom classes as an NSNumber where they should be NSString OR if you are in error sending a `length` message to an NSNumber where really you want some other method.

Comment: @noobsmgoobs I have already answered my question thanks for the answer though